# named_scope and .first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, named-scope

I can return a collection of objects, with only one (:limit => 1) but is there a way to return the .first() object only, like not within a collection?

```
named_scope :profile, :conditions => {:association => 'owner', :resource_type => 'Profile'}, :limit => 1    # => collection of 1 profile but I want the profile only NOT in a collection or array
```

the workaround is simply to apply .first() to the results, but I'd just like to clean up the code and make it less error prone.

Comment: I would have to say the vote is unanimous, A method it is, and works quite well, first time I see the where(), quite handy. Thanks all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll probably need to create a class method instead:

```
def self.profile
  where(:association => 'owner', :resource_type => 'Profile').first
end
```

Note that with Rails 3 you should be using the `where(...)` syntax, and that when doing `.first`, you don't need to specify the limit.

Answer (score 5):

First off, if you're using Rails 3 you should be using `scope` instead of `named_scope`. Same thing, different, err, name (`named_scope` will still work, but it is deprecated). Now that that is out of the way…

A scope (or named scope) takes two arguments (a symbol and either a lambda or a hash) and defines a class method on that model that returns an ActiveRecord::Relation, which is why you're able to chain methods on it.

`first`, like `find` or `all`, returns an actual result from the database. For this reason it won't work in a scope.

All that said, you can define your own class method on your model that gives the behavior you're wanting (as 2 people already answered while I was typing this). This is actually recommended over using scopes by many well-respected devs in the Rails community. Since using the `scope` class macro just defines class methods itself anyways, there isn't really a downside to this, and it has the benefit of flexibility (like in your case here).

Comment: LOL, I'm such a lame, I saw the deprecation warnings but never realized (or read them!) they were related to my newly added named_scopes, thanks for making me see the light, changing to scope.

Answer (score 3):

Define a class method to do this:

```
def profile
  where(:association => "owner", :resource_type => 'Profile').first
end
```

The `first` already does an implicit `limit 1` on the query, AND will order it by the primary key of the table so you'll always get the first.